How to make enemies navigate around each other in a grid-based game?
I am making a 2D top-down grid-based game where the movement is similar to older Pokémon games so it's locked to a grid. I implemented A* pathfinding for my enemies with a bool[,] that indicates walkable and non-walkable cells.
I have a GridController that handles smooth movement using Vector2.Lerp and an onArrived event that enemies listen to in order to start the next step in their path. This system works well as long as the enemies' paths do not cross, but currently they get stuck in each other. The GridController detects if they would go into the same cell and simply stops them from moving.
I would like to ask for some ideas to improve my approach so that the enemies can navigate around each other.

In the meantime, I found David Silver's paper on Cooperative Pathfinding. I only glanced through it, but I think it might help solve my problem

For additional information, the game has a room system, so the enemies only have to deal with relatively small maps, around 22 by 15.

Have you tried searching for "potential fields" in relation to pathfinding?
